# Replace HTML tags when copying from Word to Wordpress TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to clean as much as I can the HTML code when copying from Word/LibreOffice to Wordpress TinyMCE editor. I'm using this code (in functions.php), slightly adapted from [here](https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2015/02/19/clean-pasted-text-in-wordpress/) :

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init','configure_tinymce');

/**
 * Customize TinyMCE's configuration
 *
 * @param   array
 * @return  array
 */
function configure_tinymce($in) {
  $in['paste_preprocess'] = "function(plugin, args){
    // Strip all HTML tags except those we have whitelisted
    var whitelist = 'p,strong,em,i,b,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,ul,li,ol';
    var stripped = jQuery('<div>' + args.content + '</div>');
    var els = stripped.find('*').not(whitelist);
    for (var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var e = els[i];
      jQuery(e).replaceWith(e.innerHTML);
    }
    // Strip all class and id attributes
    stripped.find('*').removeAttr('id').removeAttr('class').removeAttr('align');
    // Return the clean HTML
    args.content = stripped.html();
  }";
  return $in;
}
```

It works great, but I would also like this function to replace `<b></b>` and `<i></i>` tags by `<strong></strong>` and `<em></em>` tags. I've tried to play with str.replace, but since I'm new to Javascript I can't figure out a nice way to replace tags like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure TinyMCE to convert `<b>` to `<strong>` and `<i>` to `<em>` in the TinyMCE configuration so you don't need to write code to do this.  The setting is:

```
extended_valid_elements : "strong/b,em/i"
```

Here is an example in TinyMCE:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/pjhaab

WordPress has hooks for you to include configuration options before TinyMCE is invoked so you can add this instead of trying to pre or post process the content.

Comment: Thanks! I added this option using Advanced TinyMCE Configuration plugin. But when I paste from Word, I still have b and i tags. I see this error in my browser console, could it be the cause? `Deprecated TinyMCE API call: <target>.onNodeChange.add(..)`

Comment: Hard to say.  The configuration option is not "code" so it is likely not the source of that message.  When I copy/paste content into the fiddle no such error happens.